# Read from pivot-table in another excel file

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am developing an excel-file for storing and analyzing data for my job. For this, I need to use VBA to perform certain calculations etc.

To the problem: The data that I want to read into my excel files is stored in other excel-files updated monthly by another unit at my work. These files are presented as pivot-tables on monthly data with certain filters available.

Basically, in my excel-file, I have a dropdown-list where the user chooses a region (filter option in the other excel-files containing the data) and then presses a button "Update". Then, the VBA-program should read into my file from the other excel-files filtering the pivot-tables according to the region the user choose in my file, and fetch the data to my file and later perform some calculations on it.

So, I would be really thankful if someone could explain to me how I could go about this. I guess that the value the user chooses in my file should pass as some kind of argument into the VBA-program? How do I read from other closed excel-files?

I hope that my explanation is clear enough to understand what I am looking for.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit:
So I have started with a VBA-program that looks as follows:

```
strLan = Range("K2").Value 'The value I want to set for the filter option

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "source-file.xlsx" _
    , Notify:=False
Windows("sourcefile.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Blad1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("filtervariable").CurrentPage = strLan
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("newfile.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Totalt").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Workbooks.Close
```

However, I get the following error message:
"unable to get the pivottables property of the worksheet class"

I hope that clears up my problem!

Best

Comment: You could always consult Google or use the recorder to get started.  Then as you come across specific questions, you can post your code and the issue here to get help.

Comment: You need to open the file, then copy the table and close it.  You can start by using the macro recorder.  I would focus on the getting of the information first, then you can worry about values from a gropdown later.

Comment: maybe Parameterized Microsoft Query https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cUYpXIKsU, or Power Query

Comment: @Rdster Sorry, I should have posted what I have now. Basically I have this:
`Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "file.xlsx" _
        , Notify:=False
    Windows("file.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A16:G171").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("newfile.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Total").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False'´`

Comment: However, I need a way to select a filter in the pivottable and then its values instead of just selecting a Range.

Comment: @Slai I tried that one, thank you! the only problem is that I doesn't work if the source data is in the form of a pivot-table.